# Bash script to insert variables into a json payload (slack webhook) question

Tags: json, bash, variables

I am trying to insert a variable into my json payload (working in shell script) but I am unsure of how to escape the characters properly

I've tried many different escape methods but I'm a total noob at it and I either return the literal string or it doesn't run

```
SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK=desiredurl

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "*Daily Webhook Verification*", "attachments": [
        {
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "Slack post failed for webhook, please investigate: $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}' "$SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK"
```

I just want to insert the value of SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK into this portion of the code "text": "Slack post failed for webhook, please investigate: $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK but it either doesn't run or returns the literal string. I have the bottom "$SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK" working successfully at the bottom to send to my desired slack channel so I'm not worried about that.

I've got it working thanks to tripleee:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\": \"*Verification*\", \"attachments\": [{\"blocks\": [{\"type\": \"section\",\"text\": {\"type\": \"mrkdwn\",\"text\": \"$SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK\"}}]}]}" $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK
```

Comment: Do you really expect the `curl` command to return a shell command line you are sure is safe to execute as a shell command on your computer? If not, the `$(...)` around the `curl` is horribly wrong.

Comment: I apologize, I had copy pasted a part of my code and missed that. I had been passing the result of that command into a variable to verify whether the webhook was successful. I've edited my post to make more sense. I'm looking into the duplicate post but mine is slightly more complicated (my own fault for setting it up that way)

Comment: The answer is simple in any event. Perhaps see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Okay, from what I'm getting from that link is that the answer lies in that I have single quoted the entire payload

Comment: Okay I am trying the following now by removing the single quotes.        #!/bin/bash
SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK=desiredurl
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{"text": "*Verification*", "attachments": [{"blocks": [{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "$SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK"}}]}]}" $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK
but it is returning invalid_payload

Comment: The second double quote in`"{"` terminates the quoted string. If you want literal double quotes in the JSON, you have to escape them; or paste adjacent single- and double-quoted string like `'"literal doubde quotes": "'"double-quoted $variable"'", 'more lnteral double quotes"'`. See also the "seesaw" paragraph in my answer to the question I linked in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I finally have it working as expected. I appreciate your patience. I used: curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\": \"*Verification*\", \"attachments\": [{\"blocks\": [{\"type\": \"section\",\"text\": {\"type\": \"mrkdwn\",\"text\": \"$SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK\"}}]}]}" $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sh
SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK=desiredurl

$(curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "*Daily Webhook Verification*", "attachments": [
        {
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "Slack post failed for webhook, please investigate: `echo $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK`"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}' "`echo $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK`")
```

Using the `echo <<variable>>` it should just run that as a command. I tested it on my own server, but might work differently on yours. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I've tried implementing your `echo $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK`but I am still running into the same issue with the channel displaying echo $SLACK_ALERT_WEBHOOK rather than desiredurl (although the '' has added some text formatting if you are familiar with slack). I'm thinking I may need to change my approach and separate out the variable from that text line.

Comment: The backticks do nothing useful inside single quotes.

Comment: It might be worth looking at using Python instead?

Comment: agreed but im adding additional code into an existing app so that ship has sailed